# Having trouble using AS3 Webservice

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3

[AS3 Webservice](http://code.google.com/p/as3webservice/)
I'm using this library to connect to a database where I store and retrieve files that my program uses.  When I test it locally, it works fine, but when I put it online it has trouble connecting, I ran some debugs inside the library and after "DESCRIPTION LOADED" is traced, nothing happens.  Also I'm not really sure where to run traces to see what the problem is exactly, I just removed the comments on some traces that were already there.

So to recap, when I run my program offline(locally) it runs fine, it connects, sends and receives no problem.  Once online, it doesn't connect it doesn't even run the traces I have in the OperationSuccessful or OperationFailure functions.

So I'm wondering if anyone has been using this library successfully and could maybe share some tips or code that will help me, thank you!

**EDIT**

*We seemed to have solved our problem with this [method](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showpost.php3?p=1066910&postcount=2) without using that third party webservice library.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume a few things here.
1) the data server is not on the same domain.
2) the server with the data is open and not blocked by the firewall.

You need a crossdomain.xml file on the server with the data allowing the domain where the swf is located.
Something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain = "*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.  In the issues tab in the as3 webservice project website someone mentioned having the same problem except for local testing instead of online testing.

Comment: I am sure you are running into a security error. But again you are not posting any error codes or anything. Have you even looked to see if the crossdomain file is being loaded on the server with the data?

Comment: Well I am unsure how I would do that exactly.  I'm told everything is working correctly server side and I'm unsure how to check for errors there.  Secondly I don't get errors on my side, none of my traces are executed at all and from the traces I from the debugs in the library everything seems to run to fine until it gets to the point where it runs the operation.  So I don't post any errors because I'm not really getting any.  And if you want to see the library source code I linked it in my question.  Unless the problem is in how I use the library.

Comment: Well instead of developing your own method of loading data from a server for whatever reason you elected to use a third party interface. This API is probably not handling security errors. So you need to modify the code and do something like urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,securityErrorHandler ); and trace that. This seems to be a common issue with this service http://code.google.com/p/as3webservice/issues/detail?id=2#c1 This is the reason why if an API does not have support from adobe I never use it. Did you even try to put the crossdomain.xml up like i said????

Comment: We already had the crossdomain.xml sorry i seem to have failed to mention it in my first comment.  After a few tries yesterday I went and looked for another mention to access webservice and found this http://www.kirupa.com/flash/connecting_web_service_pg3.htm It works fine but when I put my webservice address I get security errors saying that the website wants to access your computer popup error.  Would that be the error I would be getting if my crossdomain.xml is not setup properly?

Comment: No a crossdomain just controls if data is usable or not on the domain the swf is located at.

Comment: Currently I'm using FLASH CS5 to see if it will work using adobe mx.rpc library instead of a third party one.  With this I tried my url again and another url found in the tutorial from kirupa.com and still nothing happens when run from facebook.  So I will add that security check that you suggested and see how it goes.